# Grouped elements in Angular2 *ngFor

Tags: angular, dart

I'm looking to achieve the following with Angular2, for every entry in a list, have a `tr` tag with several columns and then another `tr` tag (or two) that spans all the columns.

```
<table >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> field 1 </td>
            <td> field 2 </td>
            <td> field 3 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"> Long string goes here </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"> </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Repeating a single row is easy:

```
<tr *ngFor="let good of data['goods']; let i = index">
    <td> good['field1'] </td>
    <td> good['field2'] </td>
    <td> good['field3'] </td>
</tr>
```

In order to repeat two `tr` tags at a time, I'd have to wrap the `tr` tag in something:

```
<span *ngFor="let good of data['goods']; let i = index">
    <tr>
        <td> good['field1'] </td>
        <td> good['field2'] </td>
        <td> good['field3'] </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"> good['field4'] </td>
    </tr>
</span>
```

but since this is a table, it won't fly wrapping a group of rows inside a span since this will give me:

```
<table>
    <span>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </span>
    <span>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </span>
    <span>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </span>
</table>
```

Does Angular2 have a magical component that allows you to group components, but then disappears out of the generated HTML (unlike the span is doing in the above example) or some other mechanism to repeat a group of elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an explicit `<template>` element with the canonical structural directive syntax:

```
<template ngFor let-good [ngForOf]="data['goods']" let-i="index">
    <tr>
        <td> good['field1'] </td>
        <td> good['field2'] </td>
        <td> good['field3'] </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"> good['field4'] </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Did not know that, thought templates were only good for showing / hiding blocks of html :-)

Comment: No, they are powerful. You can pass templates around and use them like `<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef">` to display them elsewhere or `<template ngFor="..." [ngForTemplate]="templateRef">` ...

Comment: I'll need to do a bit of deeper reading on templates, skimmed over it when I started using Angular2 and have only ever used it to hide / show blocks depending on a user's permissions. Seems everything that the normal ngfor / ngif / ... lacks, templates can do. Awesome, thanks Gunter!

Comment: `*ngFor` implicitly creates such a template element as shown in my answer. Every structural directive (with `*` prefix) does. You can create your own. Just check the source of `NgIf`, `NgFor`, `NgSwitchCase` and the TS tutorial on http://angular.io

Answer (score 2):

use template or `ng-container` directive

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</template>
```

or

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</ng-container>
```

same for ngIf, ngSwitch

Comment: `ng-container` is not yet available in Dart.